# access dynamic JS object in HTML

Tags: javascript, list

```
function onClickNew(objectName){
 alert(run);
 var run;
  if(run) {
   alert("already run");
 } else {
  var objectName = new test();
   run = 1;
   alert(run);
  } 
}

function test(){
 if(document.getElementById("selectL").childNodes.length===0) {
  this.list = {}; 
  document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = "";
  this.list['test1']= new mutation("test1", 2, {"damage":{"freq":2, "size":"d6"}});
  this.list['test2']= new mutation("test2", 1, {"range":"long"});
  this.list['test1'].level=5;
  this.addOptions();
 } else {
  for(var strName in this.list) {
   alert(strName);
  }
  this.updateList();
 }
}
```

I am calling the onClickNew() function with an HTML button, but I need to be able to access the object it creates after it is created.  I am unsure of how to do this.  I am trying to build a program that tracks abilities and keeps them up to date, but unfortunately once the list is created, i don't know how to get back at it to work with it.  How do I do it????

Comment: It's in `objectName`. You can save that into a global variable if you need to access it later.

Comment: ok, is there a way to have my function call name the variable? And how would I call it from other HTML buttons?  that is really what I need to do, click one button, create the list, click others to access it and update the elements.

Comment: you need to have a variable, as barmar mentioned, that is accessible to the functions you want to be able to read it. http://jsfiddle.net/sgnl/3adc0jou/ here is a basic example.

Comment: ok, that example actually gave me a much better way of dealing with all of this, since I can have the whole thing created and run through JS code now, I can easily code in the variables.  Thank you so much Sgnl.